# What is the QQuickItem::mapToItem return type?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickitem

The application below outputs coordinates mapped from one `QQuickItem` to another. According to the docs:

> `object mapToItem(Item item, real x, real y)`
>   Maps the point (x, y) or rect (x, y, width, height), which is in this item's coordinate  system, to item's coordinate system, and returns an object with x and y (and optionally  width and height) properties matching the mapped coordinate.

I expect the output to be something like this:

> 0 0
>   1 1
>   2 2

but I get:

```
QPointF(9, 6)   100  
QPointF(9, 5)   100  
QPointF(8, 5)   100
```

Why is the type of the `mapped.x` a `QPointF`? I expected it to be a floating-point value. What is an actual `mapped` type?

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: r0
        color: "green"
        Rectangle {
            x: 50; y:100; width: 100; height: 100;
            id: r
            color: "yellow"
            MouseArea {
                id: mousearea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onPositionChanged: {
                    var mouseP = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
                    var mapped = r.mapToItem(r0, mouseP);
                    console.log(mapped.x, ' ', mapped.y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE1:** [QQuickItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qquickitem.html) has `mapToItem` with 2 args and [Item](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-item.html) has `mapToItem` with 3 args. Which one is called in the code above?

Comment: I've looked at [`QQuickItem::mapToItem(QQmlV4Function *args)`](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp.html#_ZNK10QQuickItem9mapToItemEP14QQmlV4Function) and I can't figure out why type of `mapped.x` is `QPointF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `mapToItem` expects 3 parameters. You don't need to create a point first.

```
onPositionChanged: {
    var mapped = r.mapToItem(r0, mouse.x, mouse.y);
    console.log(mapped.x, ' ', mapped.y);
}
```

**Background note**: This seems to be kind of a bug, which I just [reported](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36042).

**Your code calls QQuickItem::mapToItem()** for two reasons. First, `QQuickItem::mapToItem(const QQuickItem *item, const QPointF &point) const;` is not *INVOKABLE*, i.e. it is not exposed from C++ to QML. Second, `QQuickItem::mapToItem(const QQuickItem *item, const QPointF &point) const;` returns a `QPointF` directly who's internal properties are called `xp` and `yp` instead of `x` and `y` (this can be observed using the debugger).

In `QQuickItem::mapToItem()` `x` and `y` are forced by C++ to be of type `qreal`, which is an alias for the C++ `double`. Even `if (v = (*args)[1])->asDouble()` freaks out completely, `x` must be

- ordinary double value
- NaN
- +∞
- −∞
- -0
- +0.

In your case it should be `NaN`. `y = 0` because parameter 3 is not set. Thus a point `(NaN, 0)` is created. From that point on, the rest of the calculations don't make any sense but error handling is missing.

There is a new JavaScript engine used from Qt 5.2 on. In 5.1 and before, V8 was used, which returns a `NaN` instead of a `QPointF` to QML.

Comment: Well, it's clear now. The last one -- how does `mapped.x` become `QPointF`?

Comment: I can't tell. But as far as I can see, the C++ functions to handle Javascript values are not exact science. This might be related to Javascript being dynamically typed.

Comment: As far as I understand, `mapToItem` uses `QQmlV4Function *` for the args and for the result. When we pass incorrect 2nd argument it, probably fail on `(v = (*args)[1])->asDouble()`. After that engine treat arg `x` like result's field named `x`. Seems like that. Thanks  for response :)

Comment: ... so that's why `mapped.x` is `QPointF`. `mapped.x` is just 2nd arg.

Comment: `x` and `y` are forced by C++ to be of type `qreal`, which is an alias for the C++ `double`. Even if `(v = (*args)[1])->asDouble()` freaks out completely, `x` must be an ordinary double value, `NaN`, `+∞`, `−∞`, `-0`, `+0`. In your case it sould be `NaN`. `y = 0`. A point `(NaN, 0)` is created. From that point on, the rest of the calculations don't make any sense but error handling is missing. There is a new Javascript engine used from Qt 5.2 on. In 5.1 and before, V8 was used, which returns a `NaN` instead of a `QPointF` to QML.

Comment: You might sum this up somehow and add to your answer.